# Chart Web Part Data Aggregations

Tags: chart-web-part, chart

I have a list with the following sample data:

```
Title  |  Rank1   |    Rank2
Foo    |    2     |      4
Foo    |    4     |      6
Foo    |    6     |      8
```

Trying to construct a Column Chart around just "Rank1" data as an aggregated average.  For example, expecting a single column to appear with the value of "4" (the average between 2, 4, and 6).

Is this possible using the Chart Web Part?  Do I need to somehow configure something in the Advanced Properties?  Does the Chart Web Part not do any aggregations like this?  Would I have to pre-aggregate the data somehow (like putting into a separate list)?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the chart web part so your looking at 3rd party stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Chart Web Part does not do Aggregations, only displays tabular data. I would suggest you create a calculated column that performs the aggregation and than use the Chart Web part pointing to that new column.

One alternative is to go for Performance Point if you have Enterprise License.

Comment: Unfortunately a calculated column won't help for data aggregation across items.

Comment: True, you would need to resort to other means.

Answer (score 1):

[Plumsail Dashboard Designer](https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-dashboard-designer/) supports aggregation and grouping as well. Also, it works in Office 365 and SharePoint on-premises. Not free but good value for price - flexibility, modern view, animation, interactivity, and no coding.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

Try [Visifire for SharePoint](http://www.visifire.com/download_silverlight_wpf_controls.php#sharepoint) webpart. This user friendly webpart will let you quickly create silverlight charts. The Visifire for SharePoint supports Group Data functionality using which you will be able to achieve your requirement as you have mentioned above. Please check out the documentation link below on how to group data.

[image]

http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/VisifireForSharePoint/Working_with_GroupBy_in_SharePoint_Charts.htm

Full disclosure: I have been involved in the development of Visifire for Sharepoint webpart.

Answer (score 0):

The Chart Web Part doesn't do aggregation.

My company offers a solution that does charting of data aggregation and allows drill-downs. Here is a demo:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2012/11/06/interactive-demo-charting-in-sharepoint/

It relies on the out of the box "Totals" available in SharePoint views.

Another option would be Excel services, but it is a multi-step process as you would have to transfer your data to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Look into SQL Report Builder. It works well with SP2010 lists, and be displayed on a SharePoint site rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another 3rd party chart web part for those who are researching this is Collabion. similar to Nevron, it enables [grouping of data](http://docs.collabion.com/charts/2.0/contents/data_selection/group_data.html)